# How to check if window is on Fullscreen in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen

I made **F11** toggle fullscreen on. But how can I make it so that **F11** can both toggle fullscreen on and off ?

I tried to make an [if] statement so it will turn it off if the window was previously toggled to fullscreen but I couldn't find a way to check if the window was already toggled or not.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Updated Solution :This is the final code that seems to work without a problem.

```
def toggle_fullscreen(event):
if (root.attributes('-fullscreen')):
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

else:
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.bind("<F11>", toggle_fullscreen)
```

Comment: An easy way is setting up a variable and changing it between two numbers on click. Like 0 & 1: set up to 0 first, if 0 change to 1; else change to 0. That's all.

Comment: And please add some code to your question.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli There is no reason for me to add code now. I wanted to know how I could know if it's in fullscreen or not and I got my answer. root.attribute('-fullscreen') thanks for everyone that answered. And especially you Parviz I saw root.attribute method but I didn't know if I could use fullscreen with it so yeah thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Well, I understand you. But it is a good habit to use a snippet in your question, so others would know better what actually is going on in your program ("Help others reproduce the problem"). Additionally, maybe others would provide a better way. For more information please visit [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Happy coding!

Comment: @ParvizKarimli I wanted to update on your code Parviz it seems it doesn't work for me but BryanOakley 's method worked with a few tweaks here and there. But both of the answers were very informative without a doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method I mentioned in my comment above:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.focus_set()

var = 0

def f(event):
    global var
    if var == 0:
        root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        var = 1
    else:
        root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
        var = 0

root.bind("<F11>", f)
```

Comment: Great solution, it really helped me out. You could even do it easier: make var a bool and replace the content of f(event) by "var = not var" followed by "root.attributes("-fullscreen", var)", but it perfectly works like that too.

Comment: @LvnRtg then you might want to upvote the answer to make it easier for others to find.

Comment: I did so already...

Answer (score 1):

`root.attributes` can be called with only a single argument to get the value of that argument.

```
if root.attribute('-fullscreen'):
    ...
else
    ...
```

Comment: Got mis-matching quotes and parentheses there... (and a missing `:`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write:

`root.attributes("-fullscreen", not root.attributes('-fullscreen'))`

It sets -fullscreen to whatever it isn't